# What is a less harsh word for "rejected" user request?

Tags: user-interface

At my place of work we have user requests.  The programmers can "reject" the request and it gets status "rejected".  The word rejected seems harsh.

Any suggestions for a better word?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a wording issue, not a programming issue.

Answer (score 3):

"Not Accepted"
"Unaccepted"
"Invalid"